# '@' in URL, used in node.js http.request

Tags: http, node.js, url

I'm presented with an url with an "@" sign in it:

```
curl http://subdomain:token@localhost:9292/aaa/bbb
```

works perfectly

But I can't get it to work with node.js http.request, probably because I don't understand what the "@" is doing (and somehow can't find a clear answer on google).

Anyone care to explain?

Here's my current node.js code

```
var http_options = {
  method : "GET"
, url : subdomain + ":" + token + "@" + Config.API.url
, path : "/aaa/bbb"
};

var req = http.request(http_options, function (response) {
  // ...
});

req.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log('error: ' + error);
});
```

which produces:

```
error: ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is called http-auth. Here is another question with the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918302/http-client-based-on-nodejs-how-to-authenticate-a-request

Comment: so a:b@url is a shorthand for basic http-auth?

Comment: Pretty much. I need to look at the RFC(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ is dividing the user / password part from the location part.

the curl line you wrote send a HTTP Authenticate (BASIC authentication) with the request.

```
curl http://subdomain:token@localhost:9292/aaa/bbb
```

means: Get `localhost:9292/aaa/bbb` and do it as user: `subdomain` password `token`

I have no idea how to do that in node.js, but you'll figure it out, now that you know what it does.

Comment: awesome, that makes things clear; i'll figure out the node part

Comment: Just set `auth` in `http_options` to "subdomain:token".