# Unable to authenticate HTTP GET Request Node.js + Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, get

Im trying to send data using a Get Request, the destination is using [basicauth-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basicauth-middleware) for authentication purposes. Authenticating through the browser and through the origin program (Without sending data) work fine, I get a confirmation output saying that it connected, however the issue is that the origin program sends a small amount of data to the destination program using GET and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) but it's not being received.

Destination.js

```
app.use(middleware('user1', 'wordpass'));    

app.use(middleware(function(username, password) {
   const auth = true;
   console.log("PASSWORD ACCEPTED")
   return auth;

}));

app.get('/data', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.query);
    var x = req.query.data1
});
```

Origin.js

```
middleware = require('basicauth-middleware');

function auth(){
request.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {
    'auth': {
        'username': 'user1',
        'password': 'wordpass',
        'sendImmediately': false
     }
 });
 }

function send_data(){
    //Gets data
    function httpget() {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/data?data1="+data['data1']+"&="+data['data2']+"&online=true";
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
    console.log("Sent!")
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
auth();
httpget();

}
```

Things I've Tried:

- Switching the order, this doesn't seem to change anything
- Changing the sendImmediately to false. My original thought was that it was sending something before there was any data to send, but that's not eh case as the Connection confirmation shows up at the same time as the request is send and data has already been gotten
- I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918302/http-client-based-on-nodejs-how-to-authenticate-a-request) post from 2011 though it doesn't really seem to still be relevant and the way I'm doing it is different though If I can adapt it to what I'm doing that would be marvelous.

I'm still pretty new to node.js, and most of this stuff. If I forgot any relevant information I will make sure to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Instead of sending the GET data with XMLHTTP Request, it can be sent with the request. as so:

```
request.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/speedtest?upload="+tele_data['upload_speed']+"&download="+tele_data['download_speed']+"&mid="+ config['meraki_id']+"&online=true", {
            'auth': {
                'username': 'user1',
                'password': 'wordpass',
                'sendImmediately': false
            }

        });
```

The problematic code only allows whatever is send in that request function and the XMLHTTP is not part of that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`app.use(middleware(function(username, password) {`

to

`app.use(basicauth(function(username, password) {`

Comment: basicauth isnt defined. The var is set as middleware. Updated the post accordingly.

Comment: do you have an output "PASSWORD ACCEPTED" in the console with your code now?

Comment: Yes. The PASSWORD ACCEPTED is the for-mentioned confirmation output. Im under the assumption that means that a connection is made and authentication happens, but no data is sent. When data is sent it prints out in the console.

Comment: there is no sending data in your Destination.js can you provide full code?

Comment: I apologize, I made a typo in my post, there is an xmlHttp.send directly below the xmlhttp.open. Edited accordingly for Origin.js. Destination.js isnt sending any data, but I added a little bit to how it's handling the input data too.